# MySQL string comparison using LIKE in store procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure, sql-like

how can I make a string comparison in order to detect if a string begins with 12% or 13% using like statement? this store procedure gives me an error and using prepared statements are very very tricky, so can someone please help me on this?

```
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_trackingtest`(IN deviceid VARCHAR(15),IN timing timestamp,IN valid tinyint(1),IN latitude double,IN longitude double,IN speed double,IN course double,IN power double,IN comando varchar(45))
    BEGIN
        IF deviceid LIKE CONCAT('12','%') OR deviceid LIKE CONCAT('13','%') THEN
            SET @deviceid = CONCAT('0',deviceid);
        ELSE
            SET @deviceid = deviceid;
        END IF;
        SET @query = properprepare('INSERT INTO tracking_? (device_id,time,valid,latitude,longitude,speed,course,power,command) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',@deviceid);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        SET @imei = deviceid;
        SET @timing = timing;
        SET @valid = valid;
        SET @latitude = latitude;
        SET @longitude = longitude;
        SET @speed = speed;
        SET @course = course;
        SET @power = power;
        SET @comando = comando;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @deviceid,@timing,@valid,@latitude,@longitude,@speed,@course,@power,@comando;
    END ;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Try this: `IF deviceid LIKE '12\%%'`. The first % is escaped to match `12%`, and the second works as the wildcard. Do the same for `13%`.

Comment: it doesn't work, it has something to do with the IF statement itself... ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF;

Comment: You've got "ENF IF" instead of "END IF", that is why you get syntax error

Comment: My god, thank you very much, I'm such an idiot.